# Get size of JFrame from inside JPanel

Tags: jframe, jpanel, size, jcomponent, bottom-up

I am making a small library that lets me make some graphs for a different project I'm working on (I don't want to download another library), and I set it up so each type of graph (pie, bar, line) extends JPanel, and everything inside those graphs (Points, lines, grids) are extensions of JComponent. But in some times, like when making the grid, I need to know how much space the JPanel takes up on the  JFrame.

Is there any way to find out how big a JPanel (has to be resizable) will be on a JFrame from a JComponent?

while it is easy to find information from top down, A JFrame can get from a JPanel which can get from a JComponent, but I cant do the opposite, have a JComponent get from a JPanel which would get from a JFrame.

thanks in advanced!!

EDIT: figured it out, look at my answer to see it.

Answer (score 0):

Are u talking about how to set size on JPanel?

```
JPanel f=new JPanel();
f.setSize(500,500);
```

If you want to resize,u may use action listener

Comment: Not really no, I know how to set the size of JPanels and stuff, what I need is to find the size of the jPanel from the component... So I am adding a component to a JPanel, and that component needs to use the height and width of the JPanel to make a grid of the right size...

Answer (score 0):

To do what I was asking in the OP, all you need to do is put at the size of the frame itself as an argument in the methods that do the drawing, it was much simpler than I was making it out to be... I was originally trying to access the information without it being an argument, but I don't think that is possible, so if you have the same problem as I did then just pass it through the methods as an arguement.